# Kotlin Jackson "missing type id property 'type' (for POJO property 'data');"

Tags: kotlin, jackson

**Disclaimer**

I know there are many posts with a similar problem, but no solution is working for me. I've been trying since yesterday and the amount of attempts I tried are too many to be listed here. What I'm posting is the latest attempt.

**Overview**

I have a service, that sends a request to another service and needs to deserialize the response polymorphically.

**Classes**

This is the format I receive from the rest call. Only two properties.

```kotlin
data class ExecutionPayload(
    val type: ChangeRequestType,
    val data: ExecutionData
)
```

`ExecutionData` is the polymorphic bit.

```kotlin
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes(
    Type(value = UpdateNetworkConfigurationsExecutionData::class, name = "UpdateNetworkConfigurationsExecutionData")
)
sealed class ExecutionData


@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class UpdateNetworkConfigurationsExecutionData(
    @JsonProperty("type") val updatedProfiles: List<UpdateSalesChannelProfileViewModel>,
    @JsonProperty("type") val zoning: List<SoftZoningConfig>
) : ExecutionData()
```

**Details**

I'll add some more context, which might be obvious to you, but nevertheless.

`ExecutionData` will in the future have sublcasses with a completely different data structure than `UpdateNetworkConfigurationsExecutionData`.

Silly example

```kotlin
data class SomeOtherConfigurationUpdateExecutionData(
    val updateSomethingHere: String,
    val anotherPropertyUpdate: Int
    val anExtraProperty: List<SomeConfig>
) : ExecutionData()
```

**Problem**

I keep getting this error no matter how hard I try.

```
ERROR com.somepackage.utils.Logger - CustomErrorConfig - org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error:
Could not resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.somepackage.ExecutionData]: missing type id property 'type' (for POJO property 'data');
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.somepackage.ExecutionData]:
missing type id property 'type' (for POJO property 'data')
```

I would really appreciate your help.

P.S. I'm new to kotlin, and jackson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is remove the unnecessary `@JsonProperty("type")`:

```kotlin
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class UpdateNetworkConfigurationsExecutionData(
    val updatedProfiles: List<UpdateSalesChannelProfileViewModel>,
    val zoning: List<SoftZoningConfig>
) : ExecutionData()
```

On top of this, keep in mind that the `type` JSON attribute must match the `@Type` `name` attribute. This means that it must match `UpdateNetworkConfigurationsExecutionData`. Your JSON must be something similar to:

```json
{
  "type": // ChangeRequestType,
  "data": {
      "type": "UpdateNetworkConfigurationsExecutionData",
      "updatedProfiles": [
          // UpdateSalesChannelProfileViewModel objects
      ],
      "zoning": [
          // SoftZoningConfig objects
      ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I did receive the type, but not in the `ExecutionData`, instead I received it in the `ExecutionPayload`. Is there a way I can annotate `ExecutionPayload` to tell jackson "hey, here's the type that you need, it's at this level, and not in the ExecutionData"?

Comment: Hi @shidoro, I've updated my answer and changed the JSON. Please check it.

Comment: I guess the issue is that the service I call doesn't know what type of ExecutionData it will be. It only knows the generic type of ExecutionPayload which is a NetworkConfiguration type. This is where I thought I'd be able to map it to any subclass of ExecutionData. My mistake was that I thought jackson would know the correct subtype from comparing the payloads. Anyway your answer got me unstuck. I have an idea on what I could do next. Thank you very much, João!